Issues Importing Data from GridDB to Power BI
I'm trying to import data from a GridDB container into Power BI. The connection is successful, but the data import process fails with the following error:
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [GridDB][ODBC Driver] SQL data type out of range.
The Container Name is: goog_stock and the columns are: Date, Open, Close, High, Min --> It is a stock market.
I suspect the issue might be related to data types. Has anyone encountered this error before, and how can it be resolved? I did not found in anywhere about this.

What data types are you using for {Open, Close, High, Min}? If they're currency data types, you should be fine. (Failing that, don't convert them at all and remove the conversion step and see if you see data... even if it's all text). If that part works, it's the conversion step that's failing.
